# Return to download activity from Notificationbar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know many questions been asked on this topic but none could answer my specific question or maybe I failed to recognize the right reply anyway!!

Just like Android Market during the download of a file with progressbar in the activity and progressbar in the notification bar, clicking the notification progressbar return back to the original activity with the progressbar updated with the download progress.

I am using AsyncTask for the download and creating & updating the notification bar all works fine, but when I click the notification it return me to same activity but without any data or progressbar (blank activity) in other word it start new activity and loose the extras and all fields data including the activity progressbar status.

I tried playing with flags and intent but failed to get my original activity loaded when clicking the notification bar specially when going back to another activity and then going to home screen then press the notification bar.

I run the download by:

```
df = new AsyncDownloadTask();
df.execute(m_item.getiid(),m_item.getipackage());
```

and the snippet (I changed the notification bar just to display progress text):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView (R.layout.activity_app_display);
//get extras
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    itemId = extras.getString("id");
    itemStatus = extras.getString("IorU");
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(0);

   showUI();

}
private void showUI() {

if(m_item != null) { 

    TextView actvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    actvTitle.setText(m_item.geticategory());

    appinstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.app_install_btn);
    appudinstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.app_udinstall_btn);

    permlist = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_perm); //
    info = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);
    mList = (HeightListView) findViewById(R.id.app_perm_list);
    mList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    instTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_install);

    TextView titleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_titlebig);
    TextView companyTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_descbig);

    TextView descTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_desc);
    TextView verTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.version);

    //fill info
    titleTxt.setText(m_item.getititle());
    companyTxt.setText(m_item.geticompany());
    descTxt.setText(m_item.getidescription());
    verTxt.setText(" Version:" + m_item.getiversion());


}
   }

@Override
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "onRetainNonConfigurationInstance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return null;
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
/*
if(df != null)
{
  if(!df.isCancelled())
    df.cancel(true);
}
CN=true;
*/

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart(); 
}



private class AsyncDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
   {
  private int successCount;
  private int numTotalFiles;
  private File outputFile;
  private String pack;
  private int downloadErr = 0;


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
super.onPreExecute();

successCount = 0;
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CN=false;
  }


  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
  {
    String remoteFilepath;
String id = params[0];
pack = params[1];
  remoteFilepath = "http://www.myserver/download/1.zip";

  String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/download/";
  File file = new File(PATH);
  file.mkdirs();
  try
  {
    if(isCancelled())
      return null;

    URL url = new URL(remoteFilepath);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    c.setConnectTimeout(getConnectTimeout());
    c.setReadTimeout(getReadTimeout());
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    int filesize = c.getContentLength();
    if(filesize > 0)
    {

      outputFile = new File(file, "1.zip");
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

      InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
      int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE];
      String progress, kbytes;
      while(!isCancelled() && (bytesRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
      {
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        fos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        if(!isCancelled() ) //&& loopCount++ % 20 == 0)
        {
          RemoteViews progressView = getProgressView(successCount + 1, numTotalFiles, totalBytesRead, filesize);
          if(progressView == null)
          {
            progress = "Download "+pack;
            kbytes = String.format("%s / %s", getStringByteSize(totalBytesRead), getStringByteSize(filesize));

            if(!isCancelled() && !CN){
              showNotification("Downloading File(s)", progress , kbytes);
              publishProgress(totalBytesRead,filesize);
            } else { return null; }
          }
          else
          {

            if(!isCancelled() && !CN){
              showNotification(progressView, "Downloading File(s)");
            } else { return null; }
          }

        }
      }
      fos.close();
      is.close();
      if(isCancelled())
        return null;

      successCount ++;
    }
    else
    {
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
    showNotification("Download Failed", "Download Progress", "Failed: " + (new File(remoteFilepath)).getName());
    //updateCancelInstall();
    publishProgress(100,100);
    notificationManager.cancel(42);
    downloadErr = 1;
    CN = true;
  }

return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCancelled()
  {
super.onCancelled();
showNotification("Download Cancelled", "Download Progress", "Cancelled");
CN = true;
publishProgress(100,100);
notificationManager.cancel(42);
  }

  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
  if(prog[0]<prog[1]){
      updateProgress(prog[0],prog[1],false);
  } else {
      updateProgress(100,100,true);
      notificationManager.cancel(42);
  }
  }


  @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
 {
super.onPostExecute(result);
if(!CN){
    if(downloadErr==0) {
        showNotification("Installing", "Installing "+pack, "Completed");
        updateDLcount udl = new updateDLcount();
        udl.execute("hello"); 
        //updateCancelInstall();
        notificationManager.cancel(42);
    } else {

        showNotification("Download Error", "Failed to download "+pack, "Error");
        //updateCancelInstall();
        notificationManager.cancel(42);
       }
   }
 }
}

   protected RemoteViews getProgressView(int currentNumFile, int totalNumFiles, int  currentReceivedBytes, int totalNumBytes)
  {
    return null;
  }



   protected Class<?> getIntentForLatestInfo()
   {
 return DisplayApp.class;
   }

protected void showNotification(String ticker, String title, String content)
{

  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.download_icon, ticker, System.currentTimeMillis());
  Intent i=new Intent(this, DisplayApp.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.putExtra("id", itemId);
i.putExtra("IorU", "itemStatus");
i.putExtra("progrss", content);
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, content, contentIntent);
  notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

  notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
if(content.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancelled")||content.equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")||CN)notificationManager.cancel(42);
}
protected void updateProgress(int downsize, int totalsize, boolean cancel){

//Log.i("YYYY","cancel="+cancel);

if(!cancel || (downsize<totalsize)){
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    TextView pb_t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_text);
    progressBar.setVisibility(0);
    pb_t.setVisibility(0);
    progressBar.setProgress((int)downsize*100/totalsize);
    pb_t.setText(String.format("%s / %s", getStringByteSize(downsize), getStringByteSize(totalsize)));
} else {
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    TextView pb_t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_text);
    progressBar.setProgress(100);
    progressBar.setVisibility(4);
    pb_t.setVisibility(4);
    updateCancelInstall();
} 
}


protected void showNotification(RemoteViews remoteView, String ticker)
{
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.download_icon, ticker, System.currentTimeMillis());
  notification.contentView = remoteView;
  Intent i=new Intent(this, DisplayApp.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
  //Log.d("YYYY","2:"+notification.contentIntent.toString());
  notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

  notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
}
```

Appreciate if you can help me by code, url or any documentations that mimics the market way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used **singleInstance** in the **launchMode** of my activity, the activity comes to front with the progress bar progressing along with the download.

I figured out that it get confused only if I moved back and then home then click notification bar, this obvious since clicking back will destroy my activity and I loose history so my work around was to disable the back key in my activity and let the application user navigate through my UI menu and button.

I know there should be away to store my activity instance and retrieve it later no matter what happened to the history/stack but so far the above is enough for me!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file try adding under the activity you wish to return to the line `android:launchMode="singleTop"`. For example:

`<activity android:name=".MainLayout"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">`

This will prevent a new instance of your activity being created and will route the intent to any current instances of your activity. For more info see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Comment: this already set (I tired singletop, singletask singleinstance) and still doesn't prevent new instance creation <activity android:name=".DisplayApp" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"  android:launchMode="singleTop" android:label="@string/title">

Comment: Hmm, in that case it appears you've done everything I can think of which might solve the issue, apologies I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It seems that I need to save the instance of the activity and then restore it as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), if so I need some code help on how to save my activity view and restore it?